# LinkedIn iOS sdk not working on iPad (os ver. 8.0.2)

Tags: ios, ipad, authentication, sdk, linkedin-api

We have successfully integrated Linkedin iOS sdk in our app.It works perfectly on iPhone devices. But when i am trying it in iPad, it doesn't work. Problem is that, it won't authenticating in iPad. It just opens linkedin home page but doesn't redirecting to App. It remains stuck on linkedin home page. Even i also tried Linked ios sdk samples on iPad.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the native LinkedIn iOS SDK, or the Javascript SDK?   It's a bit confusing when you state that it "just opens linkedin home page".  The SDK would never open a browser for any related functions.  Everything is handled using the native iOS LinkedIn app from the App Store.

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanx for the reply. We are using Linkedin iOS SDK. I mean that it just opening Linkedin app's home page and doesn't redirecting to our actual app. It just opens Linkedin app and does nothing when we try to authenticate it from our app.

Comment: I have the same issue on IPad with  iOS 8.4. If you found a solution, please post it

Comment: Got the same problem, I think it is something that LinkedIn has to fix because the code works fine on iPhone. Would like to see an update/solution from them.